# MAAS auto creates an old deleted node

Tags: virtualization, maas

Do anyone know how to stop MAAS from creating node (that has been previously deleted)?

Everytime I delete the node, it auto creates it with the same specs which consumes too much resources, I am unable to stop this.

The node that keeps getting recreated is a virsh vm

maas version is 2.3.3
virsh version is 1.3.1
OS version is Ubuntu 16.04 Server

I checked one of the VMs that gets created, and I noticed that it's the same exact vm as when I tried to delete it. It's either MAAS does not delete pods (VMs) or MAAS is simply loading up from a backup? Not sure

Comment: Please provide the operating system version and some details of your VM configuration or how you are using these applications on your platform.

Comment: @xtrchessreal requesting a vm configuration is a very generic request, can you please clarify what specific configurations you're asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed by deleting the VM directly via virsh `virsh undefine <VM_Name>` then delete the POD from MAAS. Seems like MAAS does not fully delete pods.